# Index pytorch 4d tensor by values in 2d tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two pytorch tensors:

- `X` with shape `(A, B, C, D)`
- `I` with shape `(A, B)`

Values in `I` are integers in range `[0, C)`.

---

What is the most efficient way to get tensor `Y` with shape `(A, B, D)`, such that:

```
Y[i][j][k] = X[i][j][ I[i][j] ][k]
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) for the indexing and [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) to adjust `I` to the required size:

```
eI = I[..., None, None].expand(-1, -1, 1, X.size(3))  # make eI the same for the last dimension
Y = torch.gather(X, dim=2, index=eI).squeeze()
```

testing the code:

```
A = 3 
B = 4 
C = 5 
D = 7

X = torch.rand(A, B, C, D)
I = torch.randint(0, C, (A, B), dtype=torch.long)

eI = I[..., None, None].expand(-1, -1, 1, X.size(3))
Y = torch.gather(X, dim=2, index=eI).squeeze()

# manually gather
refY = torch.empty(A, B, D)
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(B):
        refY[i, j, :] = X[i, j, I[i,j], :]

(refY == Y).all()
# Out[]: tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
```